# while loop error which only occurs with a big data frame

Tags: r, while-loop, large-data

I am trying to randomly sample lines from a very big text file.
When I run my code on a small subset it works like a charm but fails when the real corpus (44mio lines) is used instead.

My code is as follows:

```
#create minimal example data frame
lipsum <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit Nullam vehicula sollicitudin justo sed condimentum Curabitur nec lorem pellentesque facilisis elit ac rutrum orci Sed gravida ac est ac volutpat Praesent vitae metus ac nisi scelerisque porta in luctus lacus Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas Phasellus massa lacus accumsan vitae sem ullamcorper consectetur convallis ligula Morbi metus nulla accumsan id venenatis et efficitur vitae diam Vestibulum auctor aliquet finibus Donec sodales blandit dolor non viverra orci fermentum quis In dignissim felis massa quis porta diam pretium eget Sed molestie ante pharetra risus mattis"
corpus <- data.frame(c(1:100))
corpus$V1 <- lipsum
corpus <- data.frame(corpus[,"V1"])


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


for(i in 1:dim(corpus)[1]){
  string <- corpus[i,1]
  nwords<-lengths(strsplit(string, "\\W+"))
  corpus[i,2] <-nwords
  corpus[i,3] <- i
}


seed_count <- 1:100
for(i in seed_count){
  set.seed(i)
  
  complete_corpus <- corpus
  
  n_words_doc <- 0
  new_doc = data.frame()
  while (n_words_doc < 1000) { # for the large corpus this will be 7846610
    chosen_row <- sample_n(complete_corpus, 1)
    n_words_doc <- n_words_doc + chosen_row[1,2]
    complete_corpus <- complete_corpus[-chosen_row[1,3],]
    new_doc <- rbind(new_doc, chosen_row)
  }
  corpus_boot <- data.frame(new_doc[,1])
  write.table(corpus_boot, paste("corpus_boot_",i,".txt", sep=""), col.names = F, row.names = F, quote = F)
}
```

This runs fine when corpus has 100 lines, but using my original document of 44mio lines yields:

> Error in while (n_words_doc < 1000) { :
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

can anybody help, please?

Comment: I guess in one of the iterations sth. in the `while`-statement evaluates to `NA`. Just a guess!

Comment: Oh dear -what a rookie mistake, thanks!